# How can I return sum in hasMany [using with ] Addonis JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

How can I return sum in hasMany relation

Here is my controller [ I want to do something like this ]

```
 var test = await test
                  .query()
                  .with('testlogs', (builder) => {
                    builder.where('status', 2)
                            .sum('work_done as sum')
                  })
                  .where('id', 2)
                  .fetch()
```

Here is my model

```
testlogs() {
  return this.hasMany('App/Models/testlogs','id','testlogs_id')
}
```

the problem is in testlogs() function it does not return the sum . it’s return null,

like this

```
"id": 2,
"thisistst": 3000,
"testLogs": []
```

How can I return something like this

```
"id": 2,
"thisistst": 3000,
"testLogs": [
    'sum': 30000
]
```